# HTML beginner: code won't send email via form

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to set up a newsletter email capture form for our site. I'm a complete beginner so please be patient.

I'm unsure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Here is the CSS:

```css
<style media="screen" type="text/css"> body {
  background: #000000;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #FDFCFB;
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 17% auto;
}
.header {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin: -2px 0 45px;
}
.input {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.button {
  height: 44px;
  border: none;
}
#email {
  width: 75%;
  background: #FDFCFB;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: #737373;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-indent: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#submit {
  width: 25%;
  height: 46px;
  background: #E86C8D;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
#submit:hover {
  background: #d45d7d;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
  outline: 2px solid #E86C8D;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #E86C8D;
}
</style>
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Be The First To Know!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="http://www.buckleycricketclub.com/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" name="sign up for beta form">
    <div class="header">
      <p>BE THE FIRST TO KNOW</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>Buckley Cricket Club is almost ready. If you're interested in more information about our site, then sign up below to get exclusive news.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="SEND">
      <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="lee.burkhill@buckleycricketclub.com" />
      <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Subject" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Hope this helps. As I said I am a complete beginner so struggled to piece this together with my limited knowledge!

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: What you currently have: CSS for styling. HTML page for users to enter data for your capture. You are missing a script that can capture and do something with the user data supplied in your html.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise.

Once the you press submit the code does nothing except reload the page. I'm hoping for it to send the email address entered to my email.

Comment: If possible it would be great to have the data entered stored in a database on my sftp in a text file.

Comment: For mailing the data directly to you check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php otherwise if you are going the database route mysql is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your server handles PHP for this answer.

Change your form markup to this:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Be The First To Know!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" name="sign up for beta form" action="contact-form-handler.php">
    <div class="header">
      <p>BE THE FIRST TO KNOW</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>Buckley Cricket Club is almost ready. If you're interested in more information about our site, then sign up below to get exclusive news.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
      <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="SEND">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Now create a new file in the same directory as your markup named "contact-form-handler.php" and paste the following being sure to change the email from "YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE@DOMAIN.COM" to whatever your email address is:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE@DOMAIN.COM';
if(empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Please provide your email address.<br/>";
}
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n That email address is invalid.";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Signup notice from $email_address";
    $email_body = "$email_address has signed up for the mailing list."; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

Lastly, create a page titled "thank-you.html" and make it into a thank you page for after people subscribe.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks for the markup and php, it's nearly working! The submit button does actually redirect to the thank you page but the mail function doesn't seem to work. I've created the form handler file in the directory but can't see where in the code it's holding up

Comment: Woke up this morning to find a barrage of test emails coming in! IT WORKS! thanks very much for the help

Comment: No worries. That script is pretty easy to add to if you ever want to add a name or phone number field for your database, too. Best of luck with whatever the newsletter is for.